# Styled components with rfs sizing

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How to use [RFS](https://github.com/twbs/rfs) with `styled-components`? It seems that `rfs` has a `PostCSS` plugin but do some one used it before.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/rfs/issues/209

Comment: @StackedQ actually there is no answer in this issue, the author just have no idea about it

Comment: Based on the thing he said about `postCSS`, I won't think it's doable now, I found something similar though: https://github.com/hnzycfcfed/styled-px2vw, I don't know if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on new updates on https://github.com/twbs/rfs/issues/209.

> So RFS is a bunch of logic whose job is to output CSS, and
> styled-components's job is just to take CSS and do stuff with it under
> the hood. That means styled-components doesn't actually need to know
> RFS exists; all you need to do is find some way to stick RFS's output
> directly into styled-components's input, and you'll have them working
> with each other just fine. And, happily enough, the only SASS features
> RFS uses (rule-nesting and the & selector) happen to be understood by
> styled-components as well -- meaning you don't have to rearrange RFS's internals at all to do that!

We can use it is a way like this:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

import rfs from 'rfs.js';

const Button = styled.a`
  background-color: lightblue;
  ${rfs('3rem', 'height')}
  ${rfs.padding('2rem')}
  ${rfs.paddingBottom('0')}
  ${rfs('1rem')} /* font-size, also rfs.fontSize('1rem') or rfs('1rem', 'font-size') */
`
```